# Android Dagger get Parent Fragment into child fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, dagger-2, dagger

I have been trying to, unsuccessfully, inject the Parent Fragment into its sub fragments for navigation purposes. I have followed a couple of different posts but I can't seem to understand what am I missing in my implementation.

I have a `MainActivity` that contains a `ViewPager` with one such page containing `EventsFragment`. This fragment in turn has two child fragments `EventsListFragment` and `EventsDetailFragment`. I wanted to inject `EventsFragment` fragment into `EventsListFragment` so that I can tell it to navigate to `EventsDetailFragment`.

I know this is probably a repetition of the posts below and I really apologize for that but I honestly cannot see what am I missing. These are the posts I've found:

- [Dagger 2.10 Android subcomponents and builders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43371863/dagger-2-10-android-subcomponents-and-builders)
- [How to create custom scoped modules in dagger 2.10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43077314/how-to-create-custom-scoped-modules-in-dagger-2-10)
- https://google.github.io/dagger/subcomponents.html

My implementation is as follows:

**ApplicationComponent**

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [
    AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class,
    ActivityModule::class,
    BaseApplicationModule::class,
    ApplicationModule::class])
interface ApplicationComponent : AndroidInjector<AndroidApplication> {

@Component.Builder
    abstract class Builder : AndroidInjector.Builder<AndroidApplication>()
}
```

**ActivityModule**

```
@Module(includes = [MainActivityProvider::class])
abstract class ActivityModule{

}
```

**MainActivityProvider**

```
@Module(includes = [EventsFragmentProvider::class])
abstract class MainActivityProvider {
    @PerActivity
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [MainActivityModule::class])
    abstract fun provideMainActivityFactory(): MainActivity
}
```

**EventsFragmentProvider**

```
@Module(includes = [EventsListProvider::class, 
EventsDetailProvider::class])
abstract class EventsFragmentProvider {
    @PerFragment
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [EventsFragmentModule::class])
    abstract fun provideEventsFragmentFactory(): EventsFragment
}
```

**EventsFragmentModule**

```
@Module
class EventsFragmentModule {
     @Binds
     abstract fun providesEventListView(eventsFragment: EventsFragment): EventContract.Flow
}
```

**EventsListProvider**

```
@Module
abstract class EventsListProvider {
    @PerFragment
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [EventsListModule::class])
    abstract fun provideEventsListFragmentFactory(): EventsListFragment
}
```

**EventsFragment**

```
class EventsFragment : DaggerFragment(), EventContract.Flow {
    override fun navigateToList() {
        addFragment(navigator.getEventsListFragment(context!!))
    }

    override fun navigateToDetail(id: String) {
        println("id = ${id}")
    }

    ...
}
```

**EventContract**

```
interface EventContract {
    interface Flow {
        fun navigateToList()

        fun navigateToDetail(id: String)
    }
}
```

**EventsListFragment**

```
class EventsListFragment : DaggerFragment() {
    @Inject
    lateinit var eventsFlow: EventContract.Flow

    ...

}
```

### Error

```
[Dagger/MissingBinding] [dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(T)] EventContract.Flow cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
public abstract interface ApplicationComponent extends dagger.android.AndroidInjector<AndroidApplication> {
            ^
      EventContract.Flow is injected at
          EventsListFragment.eventsFlow
      EventsListFragment is injected at
          dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(T)
  component path: ApplicationComponent →EventsListProvider_ProvideEventsListFragmentFactory.EventsListFragmentSubcomponent
```

I may be using a anti-pattern but this is what got me working to this point. Im open to changes that may help me achieve this

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: Sorry just added the error

Comment: Your EventsListFragment needs an EventContract.Flow . For this reason, you must add the module capable of providing an EventContract.Flow (EventsFragmentModule) to the @ContributesAndroidInjector modules for that fragment. This said, I'm not sure how it's going to work

Answer (score 1):

The error is caused by the following module:

```
@Module
class EventsFragmentModule {
     @Binds
     abstract fun providesEventListView(eventsFragment: EventsFragment): EventContract.Flow
}
```

Dagger would not provide you with a `Fragment` and you shouldn't do that.

Moreover, I think you misunderstand the meaning of `@ContributesAndroidInjector`. It means creating an `AndroidInjector` for you but proving an instance.

```
@Module
abstract class EventsListProvider {
    @PerFragment
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [EventsListModule::class])
    abstract fun provideEventsListFragmentFactory(): EventsListFragment
}
```

So you should pass your `EventsFragment` instance into the module like this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28224927/injecting-generics-in-dagger) instead of using field injection.